# (How) Can I determine the version of the c99 compiler on my machine?

Tags: unix, c99

Is there a command line flag, or something similar, that I can use to get `c99` to print it's version?

I'm looking for output similar to `gcc`'s `-v` flag, which gives me:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

I really only care about the Target: line and the last line.

Comment: Not sure if this is an option with c99 but is there a man page? Those will note the version sometimes. I didn't see a `-v` or similar option from googling :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c99 --version

```
~$c99 --version
gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
```

also try c99 --help

```
~$ c99 --help
Usage: gcc [options] file...
Options:
  -pass-exit-codes         Exit with highest error code from a phase
  --help                   Display this information
  --target-help            Display target specific command line options
  --help={target|optimizers|warnings|params|[^]{joined|separate|undocumented}}[,...]
                           Display specific types of command line options
  (Use '-v --help' to display command line options of sub-processes)
  --version                Display compiler version information
  -dumpspecs               Display all of the built in spec strings
  -dumpversion             Display the version of the compiler
  -dumpmachine             Display the compiler's target processor
  -print-search-dirs       Display the directories in the compiler's search path
  -print-libgcc-file-name  Display the name of the compiler's companion library
  -print-file-name=<lib>   Display the full path to library <lib>
  -print-prog-name=<prog>  Display the full path to compiler component <prog>
  -print-multi-directory   Display the root directory for versions of libgcc
  -print-multi-lib         Display the mapping between command line options and
                           multiple library search directories
  -print-multi-os-directory Display the relative path to OS libraries
  -print-sysroot           Display the target libraries directory
  -print-sysroot-headers-suffix Display the sysroot suffix used to find headers
  -Wa,<options>            Pass comma-separated <options> on to the assembler
  -Wp,<options>            Pass comma-separated <options> on to the preprocessor
  -Wl,<options>            Pass comma-separated <options> on to the linker
  -Xassembler <arg>        Pass <arg> on to the assembler
  -Xpreprocessor <arg>     Pass <arg> on to the preprocessor
  -Xlinker <arg>           Pass <arg> on to the linker
  -combine                 Pass multiple source files to compiler at once
  -save-temps              Do not delete intermediate files
  -pipe                    Use pipes rather than intermediate files
  -time                    Time the execution of each subprocess
  -specs=<file>            Override built-in specs with the contents of <file>
  -std=<standard>          Assume that the input sources are for <standard>
  --sysroot=<directory>    Use <directory> as the root directory for headers
                           and libraries
  -B <directory>           Add <directory> to the compiler's search paths
  -b <machine>             Run gcc for target <machine>, if installed
  -V <version>             Run gcc version number <version>, if installed
  -v                       Display the programs invoked by the compiler
  -###                     Like -v but options quoted and commands not executed
  -E                       Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link
  -S                       Compile only; do not assemble or link
  -c                       Compile and assemble, but do not link
  -o <file>                Place the output into <file>
  -x <language>            Specify the language of the following input files
                           Permissible languages include: c c++ assembler none
                           'none' means revert to the default behavior of
                           guessing the language based on the file's extension

Options starting with -g, -f, -m, -O, -W, or --param are automatically
 passed on to the various sub-processes invoked by gcc.  In order to pass
 other options on to these processes the -W<letter> options must be used.
```

Comment: Interesting... My `c99 --version` and `c99 --help` both gave me `c99: illegal option -- -`. Seems like something Apple specific.

Comment: for debian 6.0.6 /usr/bin/c99 is symlink to /etc/alternatives/c99, which is symlink to /usr/bin/c99-gcc